# Keras shared LSTM bad performance

Tags: python, classification, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I'm new to deep learning, and in particular to Keras. I'm using the `sts` dataset
at https://github.com/brmson/dataset-sts/blob/master/data/sts/sick2014/SICK_train.txt
to model the `entailment_judgment` categorical variable.

The data is very simple: two sentences and the categorical target. I'm also using a pre-trained
`Glove` embedding (`glove.6B.100d.txt`), which you can download at http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip.

The problem is that a get an accuracy of ~65%, which I suspect is very low for this dataset. Another interesting thing is that,
if I use a **random** embedding vector, I still get ~65% accuracy, which tells me `Glove` is making no difference at all. Here's the relevant code:

```
EMBED_SIZE = 100
MAX_WORDS = 1000
MAX_SEQ = 20

# Keras tokenizer, stop words were not removed!
# texts contain all sentences
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = MAX_WORDS)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts)

# q1 and q2 are the individual sentences
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
q1 = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(q1), maxlen = MAX_SEQ)
q2 = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(q2), maxlen = MAX_SEQ)
labels = to_categorical(labels)

# load glove and create embedding matrix
embeddings_index = load_embed()
embedding_matrix = get_embedding_matrix(word_index, embeddings_index)

I1 = Input(shape = (MAX_SEQ, ), dtype='int32')
I2 = Input(shape = (MAX_SEQ, ), dtype='int32')

embedding_layer = Embedding(input_dim = len(word_index) + 1,
                        output_dim = EMBED_SIZE,
                        weights = [embedding_matrix],
                        input_length = MAX_SEQ,
                        trainable = False)

o1 = embedding_layer(I1)
o2 = embedding_layer(I2)
shared_lstm = LSTM(20, return_sequences=False)

l1 = shared_lstm(o1)
l2 = shared_lstm(o2)
merged_vector = concatenate([l1, l2])

predictions = Dense(10)(merged_vector)
predictions = Dense(len(labels[0]), activation='softmax')(predictions)
model = Model(inputs=[I1, I2], outputs=predictions)

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([q1, q2], labels, epochs=50, batch_size=5, validation_split = 0.3)
```

The idea is to feed `q1` and `q2` to the same Embedding + LSTM, then send the merged output to a Dense layer.

Is there anything wrong with the code? I've tried adding more layers, but it doesn't help. I appreciate any guidance on this, thank you!

#### EDIT 1

Just to be sure, I checked the fraction of words from the text that are present in the `Glove` embedding: 93.38%. So this is not the issue.

#### EDIT 2

Just did the following experiment: for each sentence, extract the average embedding vector. Take the difference between `avg_embed_sent1` and `avg_embed_sent2` and use it as feature vector to a simple `Dense(100)` nnet.
The accuracy goes up to ~71%. So it seems that my embedding weights are being messed up, even tough I set `trainable=False.`

#### EDIT3

This paper http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI16/paper/view/12195/12023 shows some results on this particular dataset. A decent accuracy should be around 0.81.

Comment: Do you have any training output we can view?

Comment: I'm trying to run it on my crap work machine. You mean the trainning log?

Comment: A performance might improve if you set your embedding layer to be not `trainable`. Currently - you are losing your `w2v` embedding after a first few layers.

Comment: It's already set to false.